# Commercial .NET libraries for Public-key cryptography

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, public-key-encryption

There are many examples of public-key cryptography implementations on SO, code project, etc.

I want to evaluate some commercial solutions since, not being from the domain myself, would rather rely on mature products.

Scenario:

- ASP .NET application encrypts a file container.
- WinForms applications decrypts the container.
- ASP .NET application should not have access to the WinForms' private key.
- WinForms' application should not have access to the ASP .NET application's private key.

Result: Strong encryption, tamper-proofing and identity verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that SSL won't work for what you have in mind. It seems that you are trying to get secure communication and authentication between a client and a server. Use SSL for this. In fact, that's probably the best you can get on the server side for security because of where you'd have store the encryption keys. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10326474/980922) for an in depth explication.

If you want to secure data on the client(not from the user, that would be DRM) use DPAPI or its [managed wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx). This is actually more secure than anything you can buy since it solves the key storage issued. IF you have encrypted data on the client and it needs to be accessed offline, you end up either storing the key on the system, making the user plug something in, or making them enter a separate password. The first one is insecure, the second two are a pain. DPAPI encrypts under a key derived from the user's login password( or smart card or biometrics of windows is using them)

### on the subject of crypto libraries

.net Ships with both a managed code crypto package with public key cryptography and wrappers to native code. Its the [System.security.cryptography package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) and its free and already installed on any windows system that has .net on it.

Minimally, you could use this to handle the public private key parts without any real effort(.e.g to encrypt the key from zipblackbox).

Several free/ open source libraries also support creating encrypted containers from a password. Truecrypt, tarsnap, and 7zip come to mind ( though those may require admin privileges to install). There is alos dotNetZip which does encryption, I don't believe needs admin privileges to install, and is free and open source under a non copy left license.

You can also make the encrypted container you want really easily, though I can see why you might be hesitant to do so. Just use this [class](http://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security.Cryptography.AuthenticatedAesCng) which is written by the guys on the Microsoft CLR security, write the file to that stream, prepend the IV and tag, then encrypt the key it provides using public key encryption. On the other end, decrypt the key, read off the iv, decrypt the data, verify the tags match, and then your good.

Comment: Thank you for the details. And thank you again for the link to the CNG wrapper. The reason I am sold on public-key is that SSL will not work. The WinForms client will NOT connect to the server directly in offline mode. Instead, the content will be downloaded by an admin and physically loaded on to each client computer. Think of this as an online examination scenario without an internet connection. Tamper-proofing and source identity verification are crucial.

Comment: Ok,neither SSL nor DPAPI will work. You can do the other things I listed. Important note, encrypting data with to a public key doesn't verify it's source and because I can therefor substitue your message with mine, does not prevent tampering.  What you want is a digital signature, which again .net and cng both provide.

Answer (score 0):

Then the ONLY library you should be looking at are the Cryptographic Next Generation (CNG) APIs.  These are native on Windows, have been thoroughly tested and implement just about every important, tested algorithm in existence today.

This library also has a cryptographically secure random number generator for Windows.

You might want to look at the DPAPI and the windows certificate store for windows as well.  Keep in mind that it is futile to try and implement any security at the client, to stop the client investigating your app.  If the client owns the box, they own your app and any security you care to implement.

The standard RSA algorithms are more than suited to what you are doing, however you may want to investigate using certificates to register the public/private keys as this will make your app more adaptable and easier to manage.

Comment: Thank you for that insight. I need to learn more about certificates but it may not be a candidate since the app needs to be deployed without admin privileges on systems I will not control. I will certainly look in to CNG. DPAPI also seems out since the application needs to run in offline mode where the downloaded containers could be loaded into the application by the users themselves.

Comment: Who gave this answer a -1? The gentleman understands the question and has provided good alternatives, out of which, I am actually considering one. When marking down answers, please do consider letting users know so they can at least adapt their answers.

Answer (score 0):

Public key cryptography can be easily misused and this often happens. For example, one thing that people forget about is that public key cryptography is very slow and to encrypt any meaningful amount of data (more than ~100 bytes for 1024-bit RSA keys) one needs to employ symmetric algorithm and generate session keys. This is where security holes appear.

To address this problem there exist several standards for encrypting/decrypting data with public/private keys and certificates. They are PKCS#1 and PKCS#7 (later CMS) and OpenPGP to name a few.

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/) component library is a comprehensive security solution that offers implementations for many security schemes and standards, and it offers extensive samples and support.

Comment: Thanks. The license costs associated with SecureBlackBox are not within our budget at the moment. We are, however, considering ZipBlackBox for encrypted containers. We would still need public-key cryptography over that though. Any comments on my response to Spence above?

Comment: @RaheelKhan As you noted, there exist many packages of SecureBlackbox available for individual licensing and BTW PKCS#7/CMS functions are included in all (including ZIPBlackbox) packages. We have a product, SolFS, which is a good alternative to ZIPs as a container, and the knowledgebase for SolFS contains several articles about DRM, custom encryption of containers etc. I suggest that you read those articles on http://www.eldos.com/solfs/articles/ , they will address some of your ZIP- and DPAPI- related questions.

Comment: Eugene, thanks. Will look into the suggested options if we don't find a reasonably easy managed implementation.